# iOS: How can a modal viewController remember its properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

**Problem**: In my app i present a UIViewController using a modal segue in Storyboard.
That viewController has a UITableView and the user can select a cell. Then i dismiss that viewController and go back. What i want to do is when the controller is presented again the selected cell is highlighted. So i thought to save the selected cell's indexPath in a property and in viewWillAppear set that cell highlighted. But when the viewController is presented its properties are nil. So, my questions is:

How can a modal viewController remember its properties?

Comment: The second time you present it, it's a different instance of the view controller. The presenting controller could save the modal controller, and re-present the same instance every time. Alternatively, another object could remember which items were selected. This object could be your data model, or even more simply a property in the presenting controller. The decision you make about how to store it depends on where and how these controllers need to be reused in your app.

Comment: @Aaron Brager thanx man!Did what you said and worked fine!
Answer if you like to accept it

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is you are mixing model and view controller responsibilities.

It's a model's responsibility to remember app state. It's a view controller's responsibility to bind data to views and validate user input.

The problem is everyone cheats. When you have temporary state changes in a view controller, there usually isn't a need to break that out into a model because the view controller and state data have the same lifecycle.

In your case, the state data is has a longer lifecycle than the view controller. Break that data out into a model, then apply that model to the view controller (singleton, read from persistent storage, applied in a segue, …: there are lots of ways to do it).

---

With what little information you've provided, I can think of how this can be accomplished.

Have a model which contains the arrays `allItems`, `currentItems`, `countries`. Have a `currentCountry` property. Override `-setCurrentCountry:` to rebuild `currentItems`.

```
- (void)setCurrentCountry:(MyCountryModel *)currentCountry
{
    _currentCountry = currentCountry;
    self.currentItems = [self filterAllItemsByCountry:currentCountry];
}
```

The items view controller will contain a instance of the model. When the countries view controller is pushed the, the model can be passed along in the segue. The countries view controller will use `countries` as it's data source.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = …

    MyCountryModel *country = self.model.countries[indexPath.row];

    cell.selected = country == self.model.currentCountry;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCountryModel *country = self.model.countries[indexPath.row];

    self.model.currentCountry = country;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't quite analytical about what is happening in the app. The user selects a cell witch represents a country that filters the UITableView of the previous ViewController. Does this need to be in model? I'm really new to iOS and i don't understand MVC right yet!Thanks!

Comment: I added a little more to my answer.

Comment: @JefferyThomas i want answer in swift

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are presenting a modal view controller it is a new instance. If you want a new instance to remember the properties you are saving (such as indexPath) you could save it to the NSUserDefaults so that you can just re-access everything or you could just present the same modal view controller.

What you should do is present the same modal view controller every time so that it remembers the properties.

TO USE NSUSERDEFAULTS:

You have a property, call it _indexPath

```
NSString *indexPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", _indexPath];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: indexPathString forKey: @"Index_Path"];
```

And to retrieve the indexPath just do this:

(In `-(void) viewWillAppear`)

```
NSString *indexPathString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"Index_Path"];
// convert indexPathString to indexPath and save as _indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i don't think NSUserDefaults are the right place for storing such things. As i said, i'm really new here so maybe i'm wrong. Thanx again!

Comment: I edited my answer. You could just present the same modal view controller every time if you don't want to use NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you save the indexpath to user defaults?

```
    let index = NSIndexPath(index: 35)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(index, forKey: "savedIndex")


    //Then in your viewwillappear
    if let savedIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("savedIndex") as? NSIndexPath {
        //set the highlighted cell
    }
```

Just a thought...

Comment: Fyi, this answer is in Swift while the question is asking for Objective-C.

Comment: Yep, my bad... Good that you copied my answer and translated it to Obj-C for the poster.